# how do I average two arrays with same elements?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two arrays. I want to average for example the first index of each of them. What is the best way to go about this using Vue? I plan on averaging all indexes, but want an understanding of how to do it for just one element for now.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    array1: [
      { pizza: "20" },
      { popcorn: "7"},
      { pretzel: "15"},
      { fries: "11"}
    ],
    array2: [
      { pizza: "9" },
      { popcorn: "17"},
      { pretzel: "5"},
      { fries: "4"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  average pizza = {{array1[0] + array2[0] / 2}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method that accepts index, and returns average value. To get value just use `Object.keys[0]`, to convert to `Number` use unary `+` operator.

```js
methods: {
  getAvarageByIndex(index) {
    return (+Object.values(this.array1[index])[0] + +Object.values(this.array2[index])[0]) / 2;
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    array1: [{
        pizza: "20"
      },
      {
        popcorn: "7"
      },
      {
        pretzel: "15"
      },
      {
        fries: "11"
      }
    ],
    array2: [{
        pizza: "9"
      },
      {
        popcorn: "17"
      },
      {
        pretzel: "5"
      },
      {
        fries: "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getAvarageByIndex(index) {
      return (+Object.values(this.array1[index])[0] + +Object.values(this.array2[index])[0]) / 2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span>{{ getAvarageByIndex(2) }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 14.5?

Comment: @Vzupo, it is :) Reload the page, i have made some changed to the answer.

Comment: why is it outputting 10? different index?

Comment: @Vzupo, yes, it's 2 now. Change the index to whatever you want.